# How to get data from three tables MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables: names of products, names of parameters and values of parameters for some of products:

**products**

```
+-------+-------------+ 
|   id  |  name       |  
+-------+-------------+
|   1   |  A100       |
+-------+-------------+
|   2   |  B250       |
+-------+-------------+
```

**params**

```
+-------+-------------+ 
|   id  |  name       |  
+-------+-------------+
|   1   |  width      |
+-------+-------------+
|   2   |  color      |
+-------+-------------+
```

**paramsofproducts**

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+ 
|   id  |  product  |  param    |  value    |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+ 
|   1   |     1     |    1      |   120     |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+  
|   2   |     1     |    2      |  white    |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+ 
|   3   |     2     |    1      |   275     |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+  
|   4   |     2     |    2      |  black    |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

And how to get by one query this table (all products + parameters as columns)? I can't do it with JOIN.

```
+-------+----------+-----------+-----------+ 
|   id  |  name    |  width    |  color    |
+-------+----------+-----------+-----------+ 
|   1   |  A100    |   120     |  white    |
+-------+----------+-----------+-----------+ 
|   2   |  B250    |   275     |  black    |
+-------+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: You can construct a pivot table query, but my preference (especially where the number of attributes [`params`] is unknown) is just to return a grouped and ordered result and handle the formatting in the presentation layer/application level code. Also, the id column in your `paramsofproducts` table is, presumably, meaningless - and let's not upvote faqs

Comment: And why can't you do that with a `JOIN` ?

Answer (score 1):

I can't present the result you want, but maybe is some JSON in your result a possible workaround:

```
SELECT products.id, products.name, CONCAT('[{',GROUP_CONCAT('"',REPLACE(params.name,  '"', '\\"'),'":"', REPLACE(paramsofproducts.value, '"', '\\"'),'"'),'}]') as params
FROM paramsofproducts 
LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = paramsofproducts.product 
LEFT JOIN params ON params.id = paramsofproducts.param
GROUP BY products.name
```

Result:

```
id | name | params
1  | A100 | [{"width":"120","color":"white"}]
2  | B250 | [{"width":"275","color":"black"}]
```

edit: escaping "

Comment: You will need to escape some quotes to get valid JSON in all cases.

Comment: Thank you, it's good idea, but I couldn't sort this table by params. So, I have to get the data and create a sorted array in PHP.